# How to pass system command line arguments to the Scrapy CrawlerProcess?

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

I have a single Scrapy spider that I pass system arguments to using the scrapy crawl command. I am trying to run this spider using CrawlerProcess instead of the command line. How can I pass all the same command line arguments to this crawler process ?
`scrapy crawl example -o data.jl -t jsonlines -s JOBDIR=/crawlstate`

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
process.crawl(#How do I Pass arguments like -o data.jl -t jsonlines -s 
JOBDIR=/crawlstate here?)
process.start()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can modify your project settings before you pass them to `CrawlerProcess` constructor:

```
...
settings = get_project_settings()
settings.set('FEED_URI', 'data.jl', priority='cmdline')
settings.set('FEED_FORMAT', 'jsonlines', priority='cmdline')
settings.set('JOBDIR', '/crawlstate', priority='cmdline')
process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
...
```